# How to override method in Angular? (Version 8+)

Tags: angular, typescript, overriding

I am using Angular 8.

I am trying to override the method function for the following:

```js
/**
 * This property allows you to override the method that is used to open the login url,
 * allowing a way for implementations to specify their own method of routing to new
 * urls.
 */
public openUri?: ((uri: string) => void) = uri => {
    location.href = uri;
}
```

defined in
https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/classes/AuthConfig.html#source

How do I override it?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Don't you just create your own `openUri` method?

Answer (score 1):

create a custom AuthConfig

```
export class CustomAutConfig implements AuthConfig 
{
     constructor(json?: Partial<AuthConfig>)
     {
         super(json);
     }
     //here override the functions simply declaring
     public openUri?: ((uri: string) => void) = uri => {
        location.href = uri;
     }
}
```

And use this class

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
const myConfig = new AuthConfig({
    // Other config,
    openUri: (uri: string) => {
        // Your code go here
    }
});
```